# retrieving values from object using angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
subjectname: Object0: "Math"1: "Science"2: "Chem"
```

I have an object `user` and `user.subjectname` looks as above:

Now, I need to loop through values in the object and print in my table using angular js. How do I go about it?

To create user.subjectname, I had used

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.subjectname[$index]">
```

as I am dynamically creating input row, so this is inside of ng-repeat .

If I use `{{ user.studentname }}`, I get `{"0":"vhj","1":"tyuh"}` in my table, however, I want to retrieve values from this.

`console.log(user)` gives this structure:

[image]

Comment: `user.subjectname.Object0` have you tried ? Or share some more code to understand better. Paste your json response may help

Answer (score 0):

To loop through the keys/values in `user.subjectname` and print out the values you would do this:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, val) in user.subjectname">
  {{val}}
</span>
```

This is assuming that your object looks like this:

```
var user = { subjectname: { 0: 'Math', 1: 'Science', 2: 'Chem' } };
```

I hope you don't mind me asking, but have you exposed `user` on `$scope`?

---

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/simiyifequ/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I had expected same but though it prints out object using console.log, while trying to access it in <td> of table, nothing is printed.

Comment: I'm going to assume that your object looks like this. `user = {subjectname: { 0: 'Math', 1: 'Science', 2: 'Chem' }}; 

In which case it should work just fine. The description of your object in the question posted, is somewhat hard to interpret.

Comment: I have tried to explain it further, could you please check?

Comment: Yes, Yes, I have exposed it to $scope.

Comment: Please check the jsBin I supplied to my original answer. Modify it to your liking, but I'm quite certain it should be working.