# adding an array property to object in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object called `user`:

It has properties like `user.name`, `user.age` e.tc.

Now, I need to add an array to user object called `subjects` via ng-model.

This is what i did inside of ng-repeat:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.subjectname[$index]" 
  name="subject" ng-required="true" placeholder="Enter a subject name">
```

and when I do `console.log(user.subjectname)`, it looks like this:

[image]

Now, after this, I wanted to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in user.sujects">
                  <td>{{data}} </td>
                   </div>
```

But it does not work.

Try2:

In my my service that is called from controller, I tried this,

```
        if(dataArray== null)
                var dataArray=[];

            console.log("scop.user.subjectname...................." + user.subjectname);
            for(var i in user.subjectname)
            {   dataArray.push(user.subjectname[i]) 
            }
            user.data=dataArray;
```

so, now if I do,

```
 <div ng-repeat="data in user.data">
                      <td>{{data}} </td>
                       </div>
```

I still get nothing.

Can I get some direction to deal with this?

Comment: if it has to be array you probably need to add the property as empty array when data is received. Seems that ng-model is defaulting to object

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you needed to add an array called `subjects` to your user, why is the array called `subjectname`? It seems `subjectname` should be a child object of `subjects`, no? Also, what @charlietfl said.

Comment: or use object syntax for `ng-repeat`

Comment: possible duplicate of the following (same author, same issue, somewhat the same question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357342/retrieving-values-from-object-using-angular-js

Comment: @Jan, I meant the same thing actually, i had variable called subject nae=me but to explain, I said subjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I told you in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357342/retrieving-values-from-object-using-angular-js/31357381?noredirect=1#comment50697033_31357381), and showcased in [a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/simiyifequ/1/edit?html,js,output).

You need to use the [(key, val) in object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties) syntax to get those values out of `user.subjectname`

```
ng-repeat="(key, val) in user.subjectname" ng-bind="val"
```

---

If you need to transform this object into an array:

```
$scope.arr = [];

Object.keys(user.subjectname).forEach(function (key) {
  arr.push(user.subjectname[key]);
});
```

Then if you need to output that

```
ng-repeat="a in arr" ng-bind="a"
```

---

*edit:* after further explanation from you, I'm assuming [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/kodecejubu/1/edit?html,js,output) highlights something close to what you are after.

Comment: or conversely `ng-model` does work with arrays so if OP wants array could add empty array property before view renders

Comment: Absolutely! Though I will admit, I have no clue whatsoever what the end goal is here, apart from printing out some data on the page. I'm assuming the OP can figure out the correct way to go about it with the answers he's received so far - be it an object or an array, ng-model or repeat.

Comment: @KasperLewau: Thank you, but key, val syntax did not give the values and  as I have mentioned that I am using service to create the array, we do not have $scope in service I guess?how do I go about it in that case?

Comment: @simikaur - If you are creating the array in a service, treat it as any JS object and return it into your controller. I've edited the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/sadeyiyeje/edit?html,js,output) to show you how that works.

Comment: Let me try to give a bit more information, there is an object caller user, that I pass in from controller to service and is pushed to an array there called users.Now, before I push the user object in users, I need to attach the array 'subject' as a property of user object so that the updated object is pushed into the users . I have taken this approach sice I was not able to get the values directly using key,value syntax. Please feel free to ask if I missed any pieces of information and Thanks a ton for bearing with me.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a new jsBin. It's not pretty but I do believe it does what you just explained.

Comment: @KasperLewau: Exactly, but what it outputs is the object and I want only the values from this object, :) Is there a way to do it?

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the jsBin at the very bottom - looping through the keys of the object and outputting the values.

Comment: Got it :D ;D Thanks a ton z:)